# How can I spoof screen resolution on electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using the electron framework to open a webpage with BrowserWindow.

I am using code like:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 900,
  height: 800
});
win.on('closed', () => {
  win = null
});
win.loadURL( "http://***.com/detail.asp?bhcp=1");
```

However, the opened webpage can detect my real screen resolution. What methods can I use to spoof a webpage, giving it a fake screen resolution?

Comment: @pergy, hey man, dont care the code, I just want to know how to give a fake screen resolution to webpage.

Comment: sorry, I do care :P Have you tried play with [`webContents.enableDeviceEmulation`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsenabledeviceemulationparameters) yet?

Comment: @pergy, i just tried: 
    win.webContents.enableDeviceEmulation({
        screenSize :{
            width:1010,
            height:1210,
        }
    }); It doesn't  work.

Answer (score 1):

thanks, i have worked out this issue.
1. set a script file to webPreferences.preload
2. on script file, run code, set window.screen properties.

that's it.